# Curious: Why do some avatars have drop shadows and others do not?

Tags: discussion

I noticed that some avatars contain a drop shadow and some avatars do not. I can't make heads or tails as to when or why there's a difference.

[See here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anyone with 1,000+ rep has a drop shadow if they have at least 28 characters in the "About Me" section of their profile. See [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user) for more info

Comment: Ahh.. thank you sir!

Comment: I actually never noticed this :)